# CSS image sprite with 1x1px transparent spacer not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, sprite

Using image sprites, not a problem, being doing it for years. But I've just noticed that they have stopped working on chrome when using an "img" tag with a "src" referencing a 1x1px transparent gif (spacer).

I use this spacer/method so that I still have alt text available for screen readers, etc. Just using a div or span tag is not really an option, I need to use the image tag.

Example CSS for the sprite:

```
.rec_working_backpacker{background: url("../img/recommended/working-sprite.jpg") 0 0; width:100px; height:75px;}
```

Example implementation of the html:

```
<img class="rec_working_backpacker" alt="some alt text" src="<?php echo imagePath();?>d.gif"/>
```

I know this is all working fine (nothing wrong with paths, etc) as it's working on all other browser, but in Chrome nothing is being displayed, it's like it is seeing the 1x1px "d.gif" and using that as the image, but taking the width/height of the sprite from the CSS (using the chrome inspector). Also using the inspector in chrome I can see that it's got the sprite image, it's loaded, it's just being superseded by the 1x1px gif.

Sample live URL: goo.gl/1c9nIF

- Top of the RHS column the "print" icon is missing
- Just above the google map the "Other interesting pages - what will you look at next" box is full of empty images
- Footer is meant to have 4 "follow us" round social icons
- etc

Driving me nuts, I've got empty css sprite slots all over my live site... not what I wanted to see on a Saturday morning :-(

Anyone know anything about this? I've checked on three different computers, cleared caches, etc, seems like chrome is broken...

Comment: is this your site? http://www.downundr.com/tips-and-tricks/top-ten-destinations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be your image. I'm not sure why, but when I replace your image `src` with https://pingviin.org/images/flags/blank.gif it works as expected. Maybe whatever you used to create the gif put some strange meta tags on it?

Comment: Great stuff gaynorvader, you hit it right on the head. Stupid of me not to try a new image myself before posting on here. Resized your sample image down to 1x1px (just to reduce the file size a little) using photoshop and it works. But what a bug... all of a sudden my old image stops working in chrome. The image is old (site has been live for approx 1.5 years, has always worked until suddenly. Maybe some weird chrome update...??) Grrrrr. Anyway, thanks again. Will push live in the next 30 minutes.